# There is a fatal error. fatal: unable to connect to github.com although I tried to open port 9418 to access github and Also used https/ssh but issue

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, git-clone, requirements.txt

Can someone please let me know, what the issue below.I also tried using Https/ssh instead of git but not working.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/Downloads/sequential_sentence_classification-master$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting jsonlines
  Using cached jsonlines-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Obtaining allennlp from git+git://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp@fp16_and_others#egg=allennlp (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Cloning git://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp (to revision fp16_and_others) to ./src/allennlp
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp /home/ubuntu/Downloads/sequential_sentence_classification-master/src/allennlp
  fatal: unable to connect to github.com:                                               
  github.com[0: 140.82.112.4]: errno=Connection timed out

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp /home/ubuntu/Downloads/sequential_sentence_classification-master/src/allennlp Check the logs for full command output
```

I tried this but still facing issue

```
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/Downloads/sequential_sentence_classification-master$  git remote set-url origin ssh://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp to ./src/allennlp
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/Downloads/sequential_sentence_classification-master$  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp to ./src/allennlp
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/Downloads/sequential_sentence_classification-master$ pip install -r requiremnts.txt
```

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem.

Comment: @eftshift0 Not a networking problem — `git://` protocol was disabled at Github. The OP must choose between `https://` and `ssh://`. The OP tried but then the second problem manifested: "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

Comment: The real solution for the problem: edit `requirements.txt` and replace `git://` with `https://` then rerun `pip install -r requirements.txt` In case of more `git://` protocol-related problems use [URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+insteadOf).

Comment: Well.... it _is_ a networking problem. The port is not open. :-D

Comment: The clone URL used in the later attempts is also wrong, it needs to be `https://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp.git` (notice the suffix `.git`)

Comment: that ` to ./src/allennlp` at the end of the command line probably shouldn't be there?